# Is there any alternative of CISCO JTAPI, that monitor SIP call?

Tags: cisco, cucm, jtapi, cisco-jtapi

I am working with a call monitoring system using CUCM and JTAPI. I can monitor Cisco IP Communicator call, but can't monitor any call from third party SIP client through JTAPI. Following the below reference, JTAPI applications can only control Cisco Unified IP Phone 7900 Series that run SIP.

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cucm/jtapi_dev/9_1_1/jtapidevguide/featsupported.html#wp1148307

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately TAPI/JTAPI are not supported with non-Cisco devices.

Most phone-like Cisco devices should be supported: https://developer.cisco.com/site/jtapi/documents/cti-tapi-jtapi-supported-device-matrix/